# How long is Firebase's passwordless auth link valid for?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm following the steps found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#enable_email_link_sign_in_for_your_firebase_project

When a user enters their email and is sent a link to sign in to my app, they receive a sign-in link. After that link is used once, it can't be used again. Is there a timeout for how long that link is valid?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Today official Firebase support answered me a question about the validity of the link. I also asked when I create more links in a row so if all of them will be valid or only the last one. Finally, I asked them to add it to documentation as I could not find it anywhere.

Here is the answer:

> Email link Authentication has a longer expiration time (around 6 hours). If you'll create 2 or more sign in emails in a row, you should be able to login with the latest link being received. You'll also be able to receive an error message for example in iOS, "The action code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used" when you clicked the older links.

Comment: Is it possible to increase the expiration time?

Comment: @rbansal No, it is not.